# Symfony and uploadify

Tags: file-upload, symfony1, symfony-1.4, uploadify

I want to use uploadify with Symfony 1.4, but so far I couldn't.

Uploadify loads correctly, I choose my files, it says that the files were successfully uploaded, but the are nowhere.

(I'm doing this on localhost)

Is there anybody who met this problem before?

Thanks, Tom

```
    $file = $request->getParameter('file');
    $filename = sha1($file->getOriginalName()).$file->getExtension($file->getOriginalExtension());
    $file->save(sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/'.$filename);
```

Comment: You need to show some code. You are aware that uploadify works differently from a normal file upload? That each file gets passed to a server-side script of its own, and is not part of the submitted form?

Comment: I forgot the code, sorry. I tried with simple move_uploaded_file, but it didn't work

Comment: I recommend you to use the great [`swWidgetFormUploadify`](https://github.com/rande/swFormExtraPlugin/blob/95bda9a7456665dc4910ea06ec8126ccfd82cb45/lib/widgets/swWidgetFormUploadify.class.php) from `swFormExtraPlugin`. There is also the validator.

Answer (score 1):

in my project session stored in cookies so I found solution by create extra session storage class

```
class MySessionStorage extends sfSessionStorage
{
  public function initialize($options = null)
  {
    $request = sfContext::getInstance()->getRequest();

    // work-around for uploadify
    if ($request->getParameter('uploadify') == "onUpload")
    {
      $sessionName = $options["session_name"];
      if($value = $request->getParameter($sessionName))
      {
        session_name($sessionName);
        session_id($value);
      }
    }

    parent::initialize($options);
  }
}
```

then changed factories.yml to

```
all:
  storage:
    class: MySessionStorage
```

and then "uploader" param will like this

```
uploader      : '<?php echo url_for("attachments/upload?uploadify=onUpload&" . session_name() . "=" . session_id(), true)?>',
```

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that it's because you're trying to upload while logged into a system, but flash does not inherit session data from the browser, this means you will always be denied permission to whatever function you are trying to access since symfony thinks you're not logged in.

So you need to manually set variables in order for flash to use the same login session as the browser:
jQuery Code (needs to be in a php file, will not work in a js file):

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
  .... config here
  'scriptData': { '<?php echo session_name() ?>': '<?php echo session_id() ?>' }
});
```